# Output impedance of circuit with ideal op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, impedance

I have the following circuit which I'm asked to calculate the output impedance Zout, assuming the op-amp is ideal.

[image]

I use the following equivalent circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKT326.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I get:
$$i_1 = \frac{V_x}{R_{i}+R_1}$$
$$V_i = -\frac{V_x R_{i}}{R_{i} + R_1}$$
$$i_2 = \frac{V_x - A_{vo} V_i}{R_2 + R_o} = \frac{V_x}{R_2 + R_o} + \frac{A_{vo} V_x R_{i}}{(R_{i} + R_1)(R_2 + R_o)}$$
$$I_x = I_1 + I_2$$
$$Z_{out} = V_x/I_x = \left( \frac{1}{R_{i} + R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2 + R_o} + \frac{A_{vo} R_{i}}{(R_{i} + R_1)(R_2 + R_o)} \right)^{-1} \approx \frac{R_2}{1 + A_{vo}} \approx 0$$
$$\implies Z_{out} = 0$$

Using the fact \$A_{vo} = \infty\$, \$R_{i} = \infty\$ and \$R_o = 0\$ for an ideal op-amp.

The solution says \$Z_{out} = R_2\$. My question is : what's wrong in my approach?

Thanks

Comment: The solution is wrong. Zout = 0.

Comment: You're both correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- For Vin that does not saturate the output of A1 when loaded,  Zout=0
- When A1-out  saturates Zout= R2.

  - U1 is no longer linear with linear feedback so the gain is zero when saturated

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer. Could I ask you why Avo is considered zero when Vi saturates the op amp? Is it because Avo=Vo/Vi will be approximately zero when Vi >> Vo? Would that mean if Vi=Vsat, then Zout=R2/2?

Comment: No An ideal OA-out has 0 Ohms so Zout becomes R2

Comment: What you need to know is that an OA runs out of gain with rising f , the Zout rises from near zero  towards the internal current limiting and/or fixed R which defines the short circuit current. Just like this circuit. except during linear operation. and gain=0 when saturated same as above.  Zout=R/Aol(f) for linear and Zout=R when saturated.

Comment: Oh I got it. Avo is zero because the Vi-Vo curve hits a ceiling, which makes just plain sense. That means either way my approach was working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

When saturated, the output of the opamp no longer responds to changes in output ( Flat transfer curve). Means, \$ A_{vo} = \frac {\delta V_o}{\delta V_i} = 0 \$. So now you can substitute it in your expression to get the output impedance Zo = R2.

Answer (score -1):

I was taught an "ideal Op-Amp" (theoretical) has an output impedance of zero Ohms.  Add that to R2 and I get Zout = R2.
  (as others have said)